# Can I apply for Canadian refugee if I'm European citizen?

Tags: canada, sweden, refugees

I'm visitor in Canada and I do not want to go back in Sweden because I'm at risk.   How can I request for refugee in Canada?

Comment: I couldn't help but think of the only person in the world I know of seeking asylum to avoid persecution in Sweden, [Julian Assange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Assange). But he sought asylum from Ecuador. You can, no doubt, apply for asylum, but it might, as Patricia mentions, be difficult.

Comment: Assange was concerned about possible extradition to the USA, which limited his choice of countries. In the US, he might be at risk of prolonged solitary confinement, which many countries consider a form of torture.

Comment: Can you say any more about the nature of the "risk". On the face of it, Sweden seems an unlikely source of persecution, especially considering access to the European Court of Human Rights.

Comment: it could be mafias and stuff. but would be nice to know to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 17):

You are looking for the "In-Canada Asylum Program". See [How Canada's refugee system works](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/refugees/canada.asp).

The key points are that you must have a well-founded fear of persecution or be at risk of torture or cruel or unusual punishment in Sweden. You are not eligible if you have been convicted of a serious criminal offense.

It may be difficult to prove a well-founded fear of persecution in Sweden.